# Appended text fields not going to new line

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click the add button on my form, the first text field added appear next to my first one instead of appear in the next line.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#phrase").append('<div class="row" id="phrase"><input class="input-field col s3" type="text" placeholder="Add Training Phrase" class="validate"></div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="row" id="phrase">
    <input id="field" class="input-field col s3" type="text" placeholder="Add Training Phrase" class="validate">
  </div>
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="button" name="action" id="add">
    Add
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should not duplicate ids.

Comment: It all goes down to which CSS you use. I see you use the class "row", is that bootstrap?
Can you add there the CSS which affects this form?
Have you considered using <ul> <li> ?

Comment: Considering your html look, Also why are you appending new tags inside `#phrase`? And why are you adding duplicate ids?

Comment: @AlexJolig Yeah, I am going to add a counter later. I'm just testing adding new text fields.

Comment: @Norcino I'm using Materialize CSS

Answer (score 1):

Use Prepend and make sure that the ids are unique.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#phrase").prepend('<div class="row" id="phrase"><input class="input-field col s3" type="text" placeholder="Add Training Phrase" class="validate"></div>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="row" id="phrase">
    <input id="field" class="input-field col s3" type="text" placeholder="Add Training Phrase" class="validate">
  </div>
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="button" name="action" id="add">
     Add
   </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it not possible with Append?

Comment: .append() puts data inside an element at last index and
.prepend() puts the prepending elem at first index

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want the new input field box to appear in next line i suppose. then you can try out including break line, as shown below

```
$("#phrase").append('<br><div class="row" id="phrase"><input class="input-field col s3" type="text" placeholder="Add Training Phrase" class="validate"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I works now guys. All I had to do was wrap the phrase div in another div
HTML:

```
<div id="phrases">
            <div class="row" id="phrase1">
                <input id="field" class="input-field col s3" type="text" placeholder="Add Training Phrase"
                    class="validate">
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1

    $("#add").click(function (e) { 

        e.preventDefault()
        $("#phrases").append('<div class="row" id="phrase' + counter + '"><input class="input-field col s3" type="text" placeholder="Add Training Phrase" class="validate"></div>');
        counter++
        console.log(counter)
    });
});
```